# How to use Snowflake identifier function to reference a stage object

Tags: sql, amazon-s3, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I can descrbie a stage w/ the identifier:

```
desc stage identifier('db.schema.stage_name');
```

But get an error when I try to use the stage with the at symbol syntax

Have tried these variations but no dice so far:

```
list @identifier('db.schema.stage_name');
list identifier('@db.schema.stage_name');
list identifier('db.schema.stage_name');
list identifier(@'db.schema.stage_name');
list identifier("@db.schema.stage_name");
```

Answer (score 1):

The use of `IDENTIFIER` may indicate the need to query/list content of a stage with stage name provided as variable.

An alternative approach could be usage of [directory tables](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-dirtables.html):

> Directory tables store a catalog of staged files in cloud storage. Roles with sufficient privileges can query a directory table to retrieve file URLs to access the staged files, as well as other metadata.

---

Enabling directory table on the stage:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE STAGE test DIRECTORY = (ENABLE = TRUE);
ALTER STAGE test REFRESH;
```

Listing content of the stage:

```
SET var = '@public.test';
SELECT * FROM DIRECTORY($var);

Output:
+---------------+------+---------------+-----+------+----------+
| RELATIVE_PATH | SIZE | LAST_MODIFIED | MD5 | ETAG | FILE_URL |
+---------------+------+---------------+-----+------+----------+
```